# Why does the torsion tensor NOT vanish?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

The torsion tensor in local coordinates is

$$ T^k_{ij} \enspace = \enspace \Gamma^k_{ij} - \Gamma^k_{ji} $$

However, the Christoffel symbols are symmetric in their lower indices, i.e.

$$ \Gamma^k_{ij} \enspace = \enspace  \Gamma^k_{ji}$$

Wouldn't this mean that the torsion tensor is just the zero map? I know that it doesn't, because otherwise the whole definition would be useless. Nevertheless, I don't understand why it doesn't. Can anyone explain?

Comment: The Levi-Civita connection is *defined* as the unique torsion-free connection compatible with the metric. In what context did you encounter the definition of torsion, and for *which connection* do you expect it to be non-zero?

Comment: I think there is probably a philosophical or epistimelogical matter of distinguishing between "torsion does not exist" and "the universe is furnished with a connection that has zero torsion".  Certainly the two are mathematically the same.  I believe that the various frame dragging experiements done, like gravity probe b, have put upper bounds on the size of the torsion tensor, for what it is worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mathematics you can study manifolds that have non-zero torsion, in that case the connection in local coordinates is not symmetric in both lower indices, in this case torsion is not zero.
In physics and particular in General Relativity it is assumed that the torsion is zero, so the connection (called in this case "Levi-Civita") of such a manifold can be described in local coordinates with Christoffel-symbols whose both lower indices can be exchanged without change.

If extensions of the General Relativity are considered there are among them theories where the torsion is non-zero. In that case one would need a more general connection than the so-called "Levi-Civita" connection which can be described by the well-known Christoffel-symbols.

In practice not much attention is paid to theories which have torsion since spin (fermionic matter) is the source of torsion, but the universe is dominantly filled with bosonic matter.

An exception of this might be supergravity where metric field gets as superpartner a 3/2-spin field. Supergravity theories with non-zero torsion exist and require in that case more general connections than the "Levi-Civita" connection.